# How to customize the display of a block?

Tags: blocks

I'm new to drupal, I'm using Finder module, I was able to hide some buttons and clean the presentation a little bit, but I also want to be able to customize the search fields display, I'm not sure if I will have to develop a module and implement a certain hook or this should be done in the template.

here's how the block looks like :

[image]

I'm trying to inline those input fields and add some style to them and my question is how can I achieve this.

Comment: You should be able to do that with CSS.

Comment: Should I write a module where I put this CSS or what ? because I read that it's not a good practice to change core modules or contrib modules or even contrib themes, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: That is good advice, but as it is just adding CSS you can create your own stylesheet or add your styles to the existing 'sites/all/YOUR_THEME/css/content.css'. If you are doing a lot of rethemeing it would be advised to [subtheme](https://www.drupal.org/node/225125) your base theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the display of a block by using [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module.

> Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the
>   block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP
>   to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent
>    element of a block. Hooray for more powerful
>   block theming!

In this case, first look at the CSS selector and then add a single line to theme's CSS file such [as](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp):

```
.label { display: inline }
```

**It's about CSS.**